# jQuery map vs. each

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery, the `map` and `each` functions seem to do the same thing. Are there any practical differences between the two? When would you choose to use one instead of the other?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612320/why-are-jquerys-callback-arguments-inconsistent

Answer (score 280, accepted):

The [`each`](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.each) method is meant to be an immutable iterator, where as the [`map`](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.map) method can be used as an iterator, but is really meant to manipulate the supplied array and return a new array.

Another important thing to note is that the `each` function returns the original array while the `map` function returns a new array.   If you overuse the return value of the map function you can potentially waste a lot of memory.

For example:

```
var items = [1,2,3,4];

$.each(items, function() {
  alert('this is ' + this);
});

var newItems = $.map(items, function(i) {
  return i + 1;
});
// newItems is [2,3,4,5]
```

You can also use the map function to remove an item from an array.  For example:

```
var items = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

var itemsLessThanEqualFive = $.map(items, function(i) {
  // removes all items > 5
  if (i > 5) 
    return null;
  return i;
});
// itemsLessThanEqualFive = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

You'll also note that the `this` is not mapped in the `map` function.  You will have to supply the first parameter in the callback (eg we used `i` above).  Ironically, the callback arguments used in the each method are the reverse of the callback arguments in the map function so be careful.

```
map(arr, function(elem, index) {});
// versus 
each(arr, function(index, elem) {});
```

Comment: Wrong, map isn't meant to change the supplied array, it's meant to return a *new* array based on the input array and the mapping function.

Comment: @Seb, read my link to the each function, second paragraph jQuery.each function is not the same as $().each().

Comment: Also map() flattens returned arrays

Comment: when to use map and each. What are the performance benefits of both?

Comment: @DaveVandenEynde if you want to break in the middle of the loop using `return false;`

Comment: .each() is meant to be an mutable (not immutable) iterator. Map is an immutable iterator, because it returns a new array instead of changing the original array.

Comment: You would use $.each() just like a regular .forEach loop, but the syntax is much easier to read.  You use map when you need to create a NEW array with modified array items. Which is great but might lead to memory issues.

Answer (score 94):

**1: The arguments to the callback functions are reversed.**

[`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/)'s, [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)'s, and [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/)'s callback function take the index first, and then the element

```
function (index, element)
```

[`$.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)'s callback has the same arguments, but reversed

```
function (element, index)
```

**2: [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), and [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) do something special with `this`**

`each()` calls the function in such a way that `this` points to the current element. In most cases, you don't even need the two arguments in the callback function.

```
function shout() { alert(this + '!') }

result = $.each(['lions', 'tigers', 'bears'], shout)

// result == ['lions', 'tigers', 'bears']
```

For [`$.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) the `this` variable refers to the global window object.

**3: `map()` does something special with the callback's return value**

`map()` calls the function on each element, and stores the result in a new array, which it returns. You usually only need to use the first argument in the callback function.

```
function shout(el) { return el + '!' }

result = $.map(['lions', 'tigers', 'bears'], shout)

// result == ['lions!', 'tigers!', 'bears!']
```

Comment: `function shout() { alert(this + '!') }
     result = $.each(['lions', 'tigers', 'bears'], shout)` producing a wrong result it contradicts your answer!! https://jsfiddle.net/9zy2pLev/

Comment: @Hemant Just tested the fiddle in Chrome and it seems to work fine. There are three alert dialogs ('lions!', 'tigers!', 'bears!') and at the end `result === ['lions', 'tigers', 'bears']`

Answer (score 22):

The `each` function iterates over an array, calling the supplied function once per element, and setting `this` to the active element. This:

```
function countdown() {
    alert(this + "..");
}

$([5, 4, 3, 2, 1]).each(countdown);
```

will alert `5..` then `4..` then `3..` then `2..` then `1..`

Map on the other hand takes an array, and returns a new array with each element changed by the function. This:

```
function squared() {
    return this * this;
}

var s = $([5, 4, 3, 2, 1]).map(squared);
```

would result in s being `[25, 16, 9, 4, 1]`.

Answer (score 18):

**i understood it by this**:

```
function fun1() {
    return this + 1;
}
function fun2(el) {
    return el + 1;
}

var item = [5,4,3,2,1];

var newitem1 = $.each(item, fun1);
var newitem2 = $.map(item, fun2);

console.log(newitem1); // [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] 
console.log(newitem2); // [6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
```

**so, "*each*" function returns the original array while "*map*" function returns a new array**

Answer (score 1):

```
var intArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
//lets use each function
$.each(intArray, function(index, element) {
  if (element === 3) {
    return false;
  }
  console.log(element); // prints only 1,2. Breaks the loop as soon as it encountered number 3
});

//lets use map function
$.map(intArray, function(element, index) {
  if (element === 3) {
    return false;
  }
  console.log(element); // prints only 1,2,4,5. skip the number 3.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery.map makes more sense when you are doing work on arrays as it performs very well with arrays.

Jquery.each is best used when iterating through selector items. Which is evidenced in that the map function does not use a selector.

```
$(selector).each(...)

$.map(arr....)
```

as you can see, map is not intended to be used with selectors.

Comment: the unfortunately named each function... Not the first time, and not the last that I'll get tripped up on which one someone is asking about

Comment: map and each both have a selector-version, and a util-version. $.map and $.each vs $("").map and $("").each.