# array.map() - currentValue and index parameters switched?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I am pulling an input elements array from the DOM using the the id and using .map() to loop through the array. My code works, however currentValue and index are switched:

```
ports = $("#edit_display_control_ports > li > input").map(function(currentValue, index){ 
  return index.value;}
).toArray();
```

Again, this code works. According to documentation, the first parameter of the map() function should be the currentValue and the second, index. However I have to switch the two. The currentValue return the index of the array, while the index parameter returns the element.

Comment: [Why are jQuery's callback arguments inconsistent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612320)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are partly correct, your issue is that you are not running javascript's native `.map` , this is jQuerys `.map`, since you are calling it on a jQuery collection.

jQuery's map works differently:

> callback Type: Function( Object elementOfArray, Integer indexInArray )
>   => Object The function to process each item against. The first argument to the function is the array item, the second argument is the
>   index in array The function can return any value. A returned array
>   will be flattened into the resulting array. Within the function, this
>   refers to the global (window) object.

Take a look [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)