# drop options in dropdown box

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I am using 24 dropdowns. I want to select a driver for a position. But when i select a driver for the first position it should be removed from the other dropdowns so i can't use a driver two times. The dropdown is:

```
<select name="rijderQual1">
<option value="1">S. Vettel</option>
<option value="2">M. Webber</option>
<option value="3">J. Button</option>
<option value="4">L. Hamilton</option>
<option value="5">F. Alonso</option>
<option value="6">F. Massa</option>
<option value="7">M. Schumacher</option>
<option value="8">N. Rosberg</option>
<option value="9">K. Raikkonen</option>
<option value="10">R. Grosjean</option>
<option value="11">R. 11</option>
<option value="12">R. 12</option>
<option value="14">K. Kobayashi</option>
<option value="15">S. Perez</option>
<option value="16">R. 16</option>
<option value="17">R. 17</option>
<option value="18">P. Maldonado</option>
<option value="19">R. 19</option>
<option value="20">H. Kovalainen</option>
<option value="21">J. Trulli</option>
<option value="22">P. de</option>
<option value="23">R. 23</option>
<option value="24">T. Glock</option>
<option value="25">C. Pic</option>
</select>
```

The names are `rijderQual1` to rijderQual24. So when i select `S Vettel` for example in `rijderQual1` it should be removed from the 23 other dropdowns.

Is there a way to do this? I think it should be done with JS or jQuery?

Comment: UX-wise this sounds like a bad idea. For example, if you want to switch places between two dropboxes, you'd first have to find the one that currently uses the value you want to switch to and unpopulate it before you can give it the correct value. Imagine then switching more than two places. Maybe colour-highlighting dropdowns with the same value would be better?

Comment: hmm i agree didn't think about that.

Comment: I've added a suggestion that works somewhat like that, you could take a look. Also, your accepted answer doesn't work in Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate thru all options everytime some selected value is changed and hide the options that are selected somewhere else:

```
$('select').change(function() {

    var selectedValues = $('select').map(function() { return this.value; }).get();

    $('option').show();

    $.each($('option'), function(i, item) {

        if($(this).val() != 0 && $.inArray($(this).val(), selectedValues) > -1 )
        {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });

});​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Xff7K/1)

Comment: is there a way i can use both <select name="rijderQual1"> and <select name="rijderRace1">?

Comment: yes, add a class to quals or wrap them with a div and update selectors respectively

Answer (score 2):

Try populating your dropdown box through an array, and on each item selected delete that item from that array. both JS and JQuery would work.

Answer (score 1):

I still believe another approach would be wiser, for example colour-coding all dropdowns that have the same value selected. Or unselect the option from the first dropdown if you select it in another. That way you wouldn't deprive users from doing what they want, but warn them if they try to do something that's not allowed. Better for UX. Something a little more like this.

```
// Store text labels for options
$("option")
    .each(function() {
        $(this).data("label", $(this).text());
    });

$('select').change(function() {
    // Get selected values
    var  selectedValues = $('select').map(function() { return this.value; }).get();
    // Reset conflicting dropdowns
    currentVal = $(this).val();
    $(this).siblings("select")
        .each(function() { 
            if ($(this).val() == currentVal) $(this).val(0);
        });
    // Mark selected options as unavailable
    $("option")
        .each(function() {
            if( $(this).val() != 0 && $.inArray($(this).val(), selectedValues) > -1 && !$(this).is(":selected"))
                $(this).text("(" + $(this).data("label") + ")");
            else
                $(this).text($(this).data("label"));
        });

});​
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/NAWNP/

Still, according to your requirements this would iterate through the options, disabling those that are in use by other dropdowns. This way you can still see your options, even though you can't make them.

```
$('select').change(function() {

    var selectedValues = []
    $("option:selected").each(function() { selectedValues.push($(this).val()) });
    $("option")
        .removeAttr("disabled")
        .each(function() {
            if( $(this).val() != 0 && $.inArray($(this).val(), selectedValues) > -1 && !$(this).is(":selected"))
            {
                $(this).attr("disabled", "true");
            }
        });

});​
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/ntxmh/2/

Answer (score 0):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/zyGH7/

**another** http://jsfiddle.net/fLTxj/

*Much concise version.* This is the source: [jQuery remove options except current](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9112112/jquery-remove-options-except-current) (Very well written)

Hope it fits the cause! `B-)`

**Code**

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $(".hulk").change(function() {
        var val = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
        $('select').not(this).children('option').filter(function() {
            return this.value === val;
        }).remove();


    });
});​
```

Comment: This solution doesn't show back the unselected items, since it removes them permanently. Compare to mine, which hiddes/unhiddes them @Rick

Comment: @MichalKlouda http://jsfiddle.net/fLTxj/ `:)` lol I am not sure why I got downvote anyways! +1'ed you anyhoo

Comment: I didn't downvote. Your fiddle seems to be reseting previously selected values, fix it and you have my upvote ;)

Comment: Nope, when you change second select, the first one gets reset.

Comment: @MichalKlouda lol cool, you do realize your demo is broken: http://jsfiddle.net/Xff7K/1/ select `j. button` and then see it is available in second drop down `:)`

Comment: interesting, tested just in chrome.. you are right.. but i have to leave now for a while :)

Comment: @MichalKlouda all good bruv! chill `:)` I thought I will let you know! I still donno why I got DV, anyhoo