# prevent selecting the same option from a different select box

Tags: php, jquery, html

From W3schools example (do not make any comment about W3Schools I am just using it for an example). 
A select option looks like this:

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Lets say that I have two `select` options with the same `name`

```
<select name="name[]">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> 

<select name="name[]">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Now, what I want to accomplish using jQuery, that if somebody selected an option from the first select.. he/she cannot select it from the second select. How can I accomplish that? i.e. how can I automatically remove `Volvo` from the second select if it was selected in the first select?
If it is not possible using jQuery, then how can I prevent it using PHP?

My guess is by using `array_unique`  :

```
    foreach(array_unique($_POST['name']) as $name){
        if (!empty($name)){
               // do something
        }
```

**[Edit after posting the question]**

this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001805/prevent-multiple-selections-of-same-value?rq=1) is relevant to mine. However, I do not want the option to be disabled.. I want the option to be removed or hidden. Also, I would like to see how it can be done using PHP

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jFMhP/

To go through all selects, make the javascript like:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var myOpt = [];
    $("select").each(function () {
        myOpt.push($(this).val());
    });
    $("select").each(function () {
        $(this).find("option").prop('hidden', false);
        var sel = $(this);
        $.each(myOpt, function(key, value) {
            if((value != "") && (value != sel.val())) {
                sel.find("option").filter('[value="' + value +'"]').prop('hidden', true);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And that will remove the options from all other selects.

**Alternate Option**

Alternate Option to only use 'named' selectors jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jlawrence/HUkRa/2/
Code:

```
$('select[name="name[]"]').change(function() {
    var myName = '[name="name[]"]';
    var myOpt = [];
    $("select"+ myName).each(function () {
        myOpt.push($(this).val());
    });
    $("select"+ myName).each(function () {
        $(this).find("option").prop('hidden', false);
        var sel = $(this);
        $.each(myOpt, function(key, value) {
            if((value != "") && (value != sel.val())) {
                sel.find("option").filter('[value="' + value +'"]').prop('hidden', true);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: (for the PHP, see the last comment from dfsq that is upvoted ^^)

Comment: $(...).find(...).prop is not a function

Comment: I used '.attr' instead of '.prop'

Comment: Amazingly, that doesn't negate the fact that `.prop` is a function, and that it works.

Comment: This answer solved my issue. Works perfectly fine. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

You can use `hidden` attribute (or simply `.hide()`, `display: none`) to temporarily hide necessary option, thus making it impossible to select it:

```
var $second = $('.select-two');
$('.select-one').change(function() {
    $second.find('option').prop('hidden', false)
    .filter('[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').prop('hidden', true);
    $(this).val() == $second.val() && $second.val('');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FDRE7/

And of course we can also make it work in both directions:

```
var $select = $('.select').change(function() {
    var $other = $select.not(this);
    $select.find('option').prop('hidden', false)
    .filter('[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').prop('hidden', true);
    $(this).val() == $other.val() && $other.val('');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FDRE7/1/

You may also want to validate this data on the server side. In this case if user selected the same values then POST array will look like:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => mercedes
            [1] => mercedes
        )
)
```

So it's quite easy to check:

```
if ($_POST['name'][0] == $_POST['name'][1]) {
    // not allowed, redirect back
}
```

or

```
if (count(array_unique($_POST['name'])) == 1) {
    // not allowed, redirect back
}
```

Comment: this works with the first select.. I want it to work with both selects. Whenever you pick a value from the second one.. it should be removed from the first one.. and the opposite is true.

Comment: exactly what I wanted. Please explain how you can prevent storing the same option using PHP so I can pick this answer as the right answer.

Comment: This is probably my fault.. and not yours because I did not explain my question enough. there are many flows in your code. First, the jquery code will only work on two selects.. it will not work on more than two. `count()` is not an efficient solution to validate.. there has to be a better way.. again, what if I have more than two selects elements?

Comment: If there can be more elements `if (count(array_unique($_POST['name'])) != count($_POST['name']))`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Jon, for my case I need to do a small change to change selected option in next select, and run the process for first load:

```
    $('select').change(function() {
        var myOpt = [];
        $("select").each(function () {
            //change selected in next select box
            if (myOpt.indexOf(jqml(this).val()) >= 0) {
                  $(this).find('option:selected').next().attr('selected', 'selected');
            }
            myOpt.push($(this).val());
        });
        $("select").each(function () {
            $(this).find("option").prop('hidden', false);
            var sel = $(this);
            $.each(myOpt, function(key, value) {
                if((value != "") && (value != sel.val())) {
                    sel.find("option").filter('[value="' + value +'"]').prop('hidden', true);
                }
            });
        });
    });
    //do the process for first load
    $('select').change();
```