# jQuery .each() vs. .map() without return

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary, each

Is there any difference between .each() and .map() when no value is returned? Is there any benefit in using one or the other in this case?

```
myList.map(function(myModel, myIndex){              
    myModel.itemOne = itemOne;
    myModel.itemTwo = itemTwo;
    myModel.itemThree = itemThree;
});

myList.each(function(myModel, myIndex){             
    myModel.itemOne = itemOne;
    myModel.itemTwo = itemTwo;
    myModel.itemThree = itemThree;
});
```

Comment: When used that way, there's no difference, they both iterate, and the speed difference is negligible, but $.map is intended for mapping.

Comment: `.map` probably has a slight overhead due to handling the new array and the (non-existing) return values. There is no reason to use it if you don't want to map anything anyway.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749084/jquery-map-vs-each

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`.map()` is designed to both iterate and create a new resulting array.

`.each()` is designed to be an iterator (no new array created).

Either will work for plain iteration, though I would argue that the intent of your code is clearer if you are just doing an iteration if you use `.each()` since that is its intended and only purpose.

As for functionality differences besides the creation of the array, jQuery's `.each()` allows you to terminate the iteration by returning `false` from the callback.  jQuery's `.map()` does not have a way to terminate the iteration.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought. I'm actually reading someone else's code and map is used everywhere, with no return value.

Comment: If you look jquery core :
`$.map` return an array.
`$.each` return the object to method chaining.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [jQuery map vs. each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749084/jquery-map-vs-each) and https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/iterating/

In summary, it depends on what you want to do. `$.each()` uses the same array whereas `$.map()` returns a new one. The order of the passing argument is reversed in `$.map()` to match that of the native `.map()` method available in ECMAScript 5. It's not all about how you iterate through the arrays/object, but if and how the original array/object is modified. A plus is that with `$.each()` you can use the keyword `this` within the function to reference the current element of the array/object.

Comment: this could be improved upon so it's not just a couple of links