# loop through each select field using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

how can get the value selected by the user on each select field using $(.promote).each(function(){});
the html code is:

```
<div class="class1">
<select class=" promote">
  <option value="Promote">Promote</option>
  <option value="DoNotPromote" selected="selected">Do not Promote</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="class2">
<select class=" promote">
  <option value="Promote">Promote</option>
  <option value="DoNotPromote" selected="selected">Do not Promote</option>
</select>
</div>;
<div class="class3">
<select class=" promote">
  <option value="Promote">Promote</option>
  <option value="DoNotPromote" selected="selected">Do not Promote</option>
</select>
</div>;
<div class="class4">
<select class=" promote">
  <option value="Promote">Promote</option>
  <option value="DoNotPromote" selected="selected">Do not Promote</option>
</select>
</div>;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a button and on click you get the values of each `select` using [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)

```js
$("#getValues").on("click", function() {
  var values = $(".promote").map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  }).get();
  alert(values);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1">
  <select class=" promote">
    <option value="Promote">Promote</option>
    <option value="DoNotPromote" selected="selected">Do not Promote</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="class2">
  <select class=" promote">
    <option value="Promote">Promote</option>
    <option value="DoNotPromote" selected="selected">Do not Promote</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="class3">
  <select class=" promote">
    <option value="Promote">Promote</option>
    <option value="DoNotPromote" selected="selected">Do not Promote</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="class4">
  <select class=" promote">
    <option value="Promote">Promote</option>
    <option value="DoNotPromote" selected="selected">Do not Promote</option>
  </select>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Get All Values" id="getValues" />
```

You can use [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) too:

```js
$("#getValues").on("click", function () {
    var values = [];
    $(".promote").each(function (i) {
       values[i] = $(this).val();
    });
    alert(values);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1">
    <select class=" promote">
        <option value="Promote">Promote</option>
        <option value="DoNotPromote" selected="selected">Do not Promote</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="class2">
    <select class=" promote">
        <option value="Promote">Promote</option>
        <option value="DoNotPromote" selected="selected">Do not Promote</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="class3">
    <select class=" promote">
        <option value="Promote">Promote</option>
        <option value="DoNotPromote" selected="selected">Do not Promote</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="class4">
    <select class=" promote">
        <option value="Promote">Promote</option>
        <option value="DoNotPromote" selected="selected">Do not Promote</option>
    </select>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Get All Values" id="getValues" />
```

> The each  method is meant to be an immutable iterator, where as the
>   map  method can be used as an iterator, but is really meant to
>   manipulate the supplied array and return a new array.
>
> Another important thing to note is that the each function returns the
>   original array while the map function returns a new array. If you
>   overuse the return value of the map function you can potentially waste
>   a lot of memory.

[**source**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749084/jquery-map-vs-each)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.promte').each(function(){
  // this.value;
  // OR
  // $(this).val();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 0;
var array = [];

$('.promote').each(function(){
    array[count] = $(this).val();
    count++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".promote").each(function() {
    var $selectBox = $(this);
    var selectedOption = $selectBox.find(":selected").val();
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/acuocgt5/

Answer (score 0):

instead of each method, you can directly get the values as an array

```
var selValues = $('.promote').map(function(){return $(this).val()}).get()
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xcsdLapc/1/