# jQuery loop through child elements to get attr value

Tags: javascript, loops

I am trying to loop through an elements children to get there attr value. My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="deal">
   <img src="/images/deals/xbox-one500-gb-black.png" alt="Xbox One 500 GB Black box art/packaging" title="Xbox One 500 GB Black" height="60" width="40" class="console" />
   <img src="/images/deals/xbox-one-additional-controller.png" alt="Additional Controller box art/packaging" title="Additional Controller" height="60" width="40" />
   <img src="/images/deals/xbox-one-fifa-15.png" alt="FIFA 15 box art/packaging" title="FIFA 15" height="60" width="40" />              
</div>
```

I would like to get the title attr off all items and combine into 1 title.

here is my script:

```
$(".deal").each(function() {
  var test = $(this).attr('title');
}

console.log(test);
```

Am i approaching this in the right way?

Comment: No. `console.log($(".deal").get().map(function(d) {return d.title;}).join("\n"));`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol `.deal` doesn't have any title attributes, you need to loop over its children.

Comment: Yeah, I meant `".deal>[title]"` or something XD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`jQuery.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) allows you to enumerate a set of elements and perform an action on each one. In your case you want to pull out the `title` and join those items together.

In this example I've simply joined them with a comma.

```js
var all = $('.deal img').map(function(){
    return $(this).attr('title');
  }).get().join(',');

alert(all);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="deal">
   <img src="/images/deals/xbox-one500-gb-black.png" alt="Xbox One 500 GB Black box art/packaging" title="Xbox One 500 GB Black" height="60" width="40" class="console" />
   <img src="/images/deals/xbox-one-additional-controller.png" alt="Additional Controller box art/packaging" title="Additional Controller" height="60" width="40" />
   <img src="/images/deals/xbox-one-fifa-15.png" alt="FIFA 15 box art/packaging" title="FIFA 15" height="60" width="40" />              
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`$.each` loops over the result of the selector, which in your attempt was the container element, not its children. You want to adjust the selector to find the children `img` tags, build up an array of their titles and finally join the array together with commas or whatever separator you like:

```js
var combined = [];

$(".deal img").each(function() {
  combined.push($(this).attr('title'));
});

var combinedStr = combined.join(", ");

$("#title").text("Above: " + combinedStr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="deal">
   <img src="http://lorempixel.com/60/40" alt="Xbox One 500 GB Black box art/packaging" title="Xbox One 500 GB Black" height="60" width="40" class="console" />
   <img src="http://lorempixel.com/60/40" alt="Additional Controller box art/packaging" title="Additional Controller" height="60" width="40" />
   <img src="http://lorempixel.com/60/40" alt="FIFA 15 box art/packaging" title="FIFA 15" height="60" width="40" />              
</div>
<div id="title"></div>
```

Comment: Great answer Josh; the .each seems more logical to me & it seems to use less memory per this answer comparing .each & map which both work well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749084/jquery-map-vs-each

Answer (score 0):

you are approaching the right way, but you are throwing your `test` var out with each pass. Also, you want to make sure your selector matches the `img` elements, and not the parent div.

```js
// this is just debugging code specific to SO
var console = {
  "log": function(i) {
     var li = $('<li />');
      li.html(JSON.stringify(i));
      li.appendTo('#logger');
   }
};

//  this is the answer
var titles_as_array = [], titles_as_string='';

$('.deal img').each(function(el){
  titles_as_array.push( this.title );
});

titles_as_string = titles_as_array.join(' ');

console.log( titles_as_array );

console.log( titles_as_string );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="deal">
   <img src="/images/deals/xbox-one500-gb-black.png" alt="Xbox One 500 GB Black box art/packaging" title="Xbox One 500 GB Black" height="60" width="40" class="console" />
   <img src="/images/deals/xbox-one-additional-controller.png" alt="Additional Controller box art/packaging" title="Additional Controller" height="60" width="40" />
   <img src="/images/deals/xbox-one-fifa-15.png" alt="FIFA 15 box art/packaging" title="FIFA 15" height="60" width="40" />              
</div>

<ul id="logger"></ul>
```