# jQuery map vs jQuery each

Tags: jquery, each

I have come across the following code:

```
var userDetailsFields = $(formSelector + " input[type='text'], " + formSelector + " select").map(function(){
  return this.id;
});
```

I was wondering if the jQuery each would be more suitable to achieve the same result from a performance perspective..

AIM: return the value of each input and select inside a form.

Comment: How about `$(formSelector).find('input, select').each(function(){ //code });` - I'd say `each` is more readable when looping over jQuery objects.

Comment: would you say that from performance perspective is better?

Comment: You'll probably save more execution time if you write the selectors more efficiently

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery map vs. each](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749084/jquery-map-vs-each)

Comment: a list/array of values (from the inputs and selects passed in) to update the same form...

Comment: I have put up a little example here: https://jsfiddle.net/mbrg701w/2/ i need to use the result which is "this.id" to update a form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var userDetailsFields = $(formSelector).find("input[type='text'], select").map(function(){
  return this.id;
});
```

**.each**  used to iterate over array-like and make something on each item. It's more generic function

**.map** - create new array base on source array-like object. It's more specific function

Speed will be the same, but semantic of task say that better to use .map