# array map, map array as a key of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I know the title might sounds confusing, but i'm stuck for an hour using $.each. Basically I have 2 arrays

`[{"section_name":"abc","id":1},{"section_name":"xyz","id":2}];`

and `[{"toy":"car","section_id":1},{"tool":"knife","section_id":1},{"weapons":"cutter","section_id":2}];`

How do I **put one into another as a new property key** like

```
[{
    "section_name": "abc",
    "id": 1,
    "new_property_name": [{
        "toy": "car"
    }, {
        "tool": "knife"
    }]
}, {
    "section_name": "xyz",
    "id": 2,
    "new_property_name": [{
        "weapon": "cutter"
    }]
}]
```

Comment: From where you are getting these two json ? if it API in you end, it is better to update query then manipulating.

Comment: @Rishi if I have that flexibility then I no need to post question in here.

Answer (score 4):

ES6 Solution :

```
const arr = [{"section_name":"abc","id":1},{"section_name":"xyz","id":2}];
const arr2 = [{"toy":"car","id":1},{"tool":"knife","id":1},{"weapons":"cutter","id":2}];

const res = arr.map((section,index) => {
  section.new_property_name = arr2.filter(item => item.id === section.id);
  return section;
});
```

EDIT : Like georg mentionned in the comments, the solution above is actually mutating `arr`, it modifies the original `arr` (if you log the arr after mapping it, you will see it has changed, mutated the `arr` and have the `new_property_name`). It makes the `.map()` useless, a simple `forEach()` is indeed more appropriate and save one line.

```
arr.forEach(section => {
   section.new_property_name = arr2.filter(item => item.id === section.id));
});
```

Comment: Since you're mutating each `section`, there's no need for `map` and `res`, simply `arr.forEach(section => section.new_property etc` will do

Comment: @EuniceChia - Vincent is mutating the first array (arr) by adding "new_property_name" to it, so there is no need to create a new array "res" which will have the same properties like "arr" now. I would actually not mutate at all and create a complete new array.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
var data1 = [{"section_name":"abc","id":1},{"section_name":"xyz","id":2}];
var data2 = [{"toy":"car","id":1},{"tool":"knife","id":1},{"weapons":"cutter","id":2}];

var map = {};

//first iterate data1 the create a map of all the objects by its ids
data1.forEach( function( obj ){ map[ obj.id ] = obj });

//Iterate data2 and populate the new_property_name of all the ids 
data2.forEach( function(obj){ 
  var id = obj.id;
  map[ id ].new_property_name = map[ id ].new_property_name || []; 
  delete obj.id;
  map[ id ].new_property_name.push( obj ); 
});

//just get only the values from the map
var output = Object.keys(map).map(function(key){ return map[ key ] });
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use ah hash table for look up and build a new object for inserting into the `new_property_name` array.

```js
var array1 = [{ "section_name": "abc", "id": 1 }, { "section_name": "xyz", "id": 2 }],
    array2 = [{ "toy": "car", "section_id": 1 }, { "tool": "knife", "section_id": 1 }, { "weapons": "cutter", "section_id": 2 }],
    hash = Object.create(null);

array1.forEach(function (a) {
    a.new_property_name = [];
    hash[a.id] = a;
});
array2.forEach(function (a) {
    hash[a.section_id].new_property_name.push(Object.keys(a).reduce(function (r, k) {
        if (k !== 'section_id') {
            r[k] = a[k];
        }
        return r;
    }, {}));
});
    
console.log(array1);
```

Comment: You can add `new_property_name` in first loop so there is no need to check in second one.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like by using Jquery `$.merge()` Function you can achieve what you need. Then we have `concat` function too which can be used to merge one array with another.

Comment: @EuniceChia I haven't personally used $.map() but this is what i have found http://stackoverflow.com/a/749119/6468641

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.assign()`

In your case you can do it like `Object.assign(array1[0], array2[0])`.
It's very good for combining objects, so in your case you just need to combine your objects within the array.

Example of code:

```
var objA = [{"section_name":"abc","id":1},{"section_name":"xyz","id":2}];
var objB = [{"toy":"car","section_id":1},{"tool":"knife","section_id":1},{"weapons":"cutter","section_id":2}];
var objC = Object.assign({},objA[0],objB[0]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(objC));// {"section_name":"abc","id":1,"toy":"car","section_id":1}
```

For more info, you can refer here: [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: wouldn't $.map be faster?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var firstArray = [{"section_name":"abc","id":1},{"section_name":"xyz","id":2}],

 secondArray = [{"toy":"car","section_id":1},{"tool":"knife","section_id":1},{"weapons":"cutter","section_id":2}];

var hash = Object.create(null);
firstArray.forEach(s => {
  hash[s.id] = s;
  s['new_property_name'] = [];
});

secondArray.forEach(i => hash[i['section_id']]['new_property_name'].push(i));

console.log(firstArray);
```