# How to select the h2 tags which are 50px or higher and change the css of them?

Tags: jquery, css

How can I select the h2 tags which are 50px or higher and change the css of them?

```
// Get an array of all h2 element heights
var elementHeights = $('.sub-services .sub-service__content h2').map(function() {
  return $(this).height();
}).get();
```

With this I get an array with the heights, but how I select the ones with 50px or more to change the css?

Also should I use .map() or .each() for this? I am a bit confused. [jQuery map vs. each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749084/jquery-map-vs-each)

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer to your title; use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to get a subset of elements matching a specific criteria:

```
var $H2_50Plus = $('h2').filter(function() {
  return $(this).height() >= 50;
});

$H2_50Plus.css({background:'red'}); // apply some CSS?
```

You can also use [`.addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/), if that helps

```js
var $H2_50Plus = $('h2').filter(function() {
  return $(this).height() >= 50;
});

$H2_50Plus.addClass('red');
```

```css
.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<h2>one<br>one</h2>
<h2>two</h2>
<h2>three<br>three</h2>



<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```